# Unable to pass values in scriptData in Uploadify?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, uploadify

I am passing file description from scriptData in mulitple fileupload after getting file description from user..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploadQueue = new Array();
    $(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
            'script': 'Home/Upload',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'scriptData': { 'description': $('#description_' + uploadQueue).val() },
            //'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            //'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'onSelect': function (event, queueID, fileObj) {
                uploadQueue.push(queueID);
            },
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false
        });

        $('#start').click(function () {
            $.each(uploadQueue, function (k, v) {
                alert($('#description_' + uploadQueue).val());
                //$('#fileuploader').fileUploadSettings('scriptData','description=test');
                $('#fileuploader').fileUploadStart(v);
            });
        });

    });



    </script>

<div id="fileuploader"></div>
<input type="button" id="start" value="start"/>
```

but somehow in **MVC controller** i'm not getting values of the description it is passing as **null or undefined** ???

```
  public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, string description)
    {
        var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
        fileData.SaveAs(fileName);

        return View();
    }
```

Please Help..
Don't know where is the mistake !!

Comment: Is your first file's data making it to your action? And the data for files after the first not getting set? Also, I can't find scriptData in the documentation but I do find formData http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/

Answer (score -1):

use this controller

```
    public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
        fileData.SaveAs(fileName);
        return "ok";
    }
```